# How do I avoid asking about mondegreens?

Tags: discussion, online-resources

In https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337601/what-does-stacked-mean-in-the-eminem-song-lose-yourself , I asked about the [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) of a misheard word. However, it wasn't just misheard by me: when I looked up the lyrics, Google Play gave me the same words (I also came across this [poorly answered question on another site](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hes-so-stacked.2459168/)).

Is there anything I could have done to avoid asking about such a mondegreen?

Comment: Related question, but about how to close such questions: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4443/what-about-a-it-s-just-a-typo-off-topic-close-option

Comment: You could stop listening to Eminem, but that's not a general solution.

Comment: @deadrat Yeah, start listening to deadmau5 instead.

Comment: It is amazing how many bad lyrics sites there are! Especially from the days when everyone bought albums!

Comment: @PhonicsTheHedgehog No relation. But he's got a good beat and you can gnaw to it.

Comment: I feel like 'mondegreen' is misleading. I think your title should be "How do I avoid asking about things I misheard?". Mainly because mondegreens as a concept are surely fair game here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this kind of situation is rare enough that you don't have to take special steps to avoid it. You can just let people tell you about it in the comments. Once you learn that the question is based on a misunderstanding, I would delete it, since it is not answerable.